# Split streaming message in multiple Dicts

Tags: python, json, dictionary, stream

I'm trying to use json to decode a streaming message but throws the following ValueError:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
  raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
  ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 23571 column 1 (char 126 - 72358378)
```

I searched in SO and the possible reason is my streaming message. If so, How can split my streaming message into multiple dicts in a pythonic way?

some lines of my streaming message:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":486174602859528192,"id_str":"486174602859528192","user_id":2455171405,"user_id_str":"2455171405"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":244223991382937601,"id_str":"244223991382937601","user_id":236405781,"user_id_str":"236405781"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":243934303371792384,"id_str":"243934303371792384","user_id":236405781,"user_id_str":"236405781"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":320790822129913856,"id_str":"320790822129913856","user_id":320634758,"user_id_str":"320634758"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":399494495630155776,"id_str":"399494495630155776","user_id":1227287820,"user_id_str":"1227287820"}}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":399528981206007808,"id_str":"399528981206007808","user_id":1227287820,"user_id_str":"1227287820"}}}
{"created_at":"Wed Jul 09 12:16:27 +0000 2014","id":486846341600251904,"id_str":"486846341600251904","text":"#RT \u0430 \u0437\u043d\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043c\u0443 \u044f \u043d\u0435 \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0443 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0442\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0434 \u043e \u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c?","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.ckhi.com.ua\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003e\"Original atok\"\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2530930573,"id_str":"2530930573","name":"\u041b\u0435\u043f\u0430\u0448\u0438\u043da \u041f\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0433\u0435\u044f","screen_name":"miki4390","location":"\u0421\u0430\u043d\u043a\u0442-\u041f\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433","url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/miki4390","description":"\u042f-\u0442\u043e \u0442\u0435\u0440\u043f\u043b\u044e. \u041d\u043e \u0442\u044b-\u0442\u043e \u043f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0435\u0448\u044c...","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":0,"friends_count":0,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":11,"created_at":"Wed May 28 21:41:41 +0000 2014","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2530930573\/1404903710","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":true,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"RT","indices":[0,3]}],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"ru"}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":295365152621080577,"id_str":"295365152621080577","user_id":710752640,"user_id_str":"710752640"}}}
```

Comment: Are you sure your JSON string is well-formed JSON? Can other decoders tackle it?

Comment: Hello @9000 I don't know if another decoder can tackle it but I got my JSON file from a streming twitter API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is in fact set of JSON lines.

## Decoding JSON line by line

Reading all the lines at once results in broken JSON data.

Reading the lines one by one and decoding works well.

With your json lines in file "jslines.json" following code:

```
>>> import json
>>> fname = "jslines.json"
>>> f = open(fname)
>>> for line in f:
...     print json.loads(line)
```

decodes and prints all the lines.

## Building valid JSON array from lines

Alternative approach is to use the lines to build valid JSON structure, in this case an array. We have to get list of the lines (as text), concatenate using ",", and enclose between "[" and "]"".

```
>>> with open(fname) as f:
...    lines = list(f)
```

Now we have all the lines in a list `lines`

Build the resulting JSON text:

```
>>> jstext = "[" + ",".join(lines) + "]"
```

And load it into dictionary:

```
>>> json.loads(jstext)
```

This works with the data you have provided.